# caption with math formula in it leads to error

Tags: captions

I have the following Latex snippet for which I get the error
`Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }. ...I\\-I&0 \end{pmatrix}$. \end{minipage} }`

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=2.5:5.4] 
        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (2.0,0.0) grid (5.9,3.9);
        \draw[->] (2.0,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {$\mathbf{q}$}; 
        \draw[->] (2.0,0.0) -- (2.0,4.2) node[above] {$\mathbf{p}$};
        \draw[color=blue]   plot (\x,{0.3+0.01*exp(\x)}) ;   
        \draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{0.7+0.015*exp(\x)}) ;
        \filldraw (2.7,0.45) circle (2pt) node[align=left,   below] {$(\mathbf{q}_0,\mathbf{p}_0)=\mathbf{x}_0$};
        \filldraw (5.0,1.77) circle (2pt) node[align=right,   below] {$(\mathbf{q}(h),\mathbf{p}(h))=\mathbf{x}(h)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\leavevmode\\
       \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            The flow map $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_0,h)=\mathbf{x}(h)$ is a symplectic transformation, i.e.
            $(\text{D}\varphi)^TJ\text{ D}\varphi=J=\begin{pmatrix}0&I\\-I&0 \end{pmatrix}$.  
        \end{minipage} 
    }
end{figure}
```

the error occurs because of the pmatrix part. Has someone an idea how to change it?

Comment: Why ``\leavevmode\\``? If you want to change the format of captions, use the `caption` package, not those methods.

Comment: This `\leavevmode` is not important. I just used it in order to get the whole text on one line. The error comes from the `\begin{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}`. Without this part of the formula it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a line break after “Figure 1”, use a proper way, with the `caption` package.

The code works flawlessly with an up-to-date TeX distribution, so I guess you have an outdated one (2018 or earlier).

In this case, use `\protect\begin{pmatrix}` and `\protect\end{pmatrix}`.

Here's a better coding:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{labelsep=newline}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=2.5:5.4] 
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (2.0,0.0) grid (5.9,3.9);
  \draw[->] (2.0,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {$\mathbf{q}$}; 
  \draw[->] (2.0,0.0) -- (2.0,4.2) node[above] {$\mathbf{p}$};
  \draw[color=blue]   plot (\x,{0.3+0.01*exp(\x)}) ;   
  \draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{0.7+0.015*exp(\x)}) ;
  \filldraw (2.7,0.45) circle (2pt) node[align=left,below]
    {$(\mathbf{q}_0,\mathbf{p}_0)=\mathbf{x}_0$};
  \filldraw (5.0,1.77) circle (2pt) node[align=right,below]
    {$(\mathbf{q}(h),\mathbf{p}(h))=\mathbf{x}(h)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{The flow map $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_0,h)=\mathbf{x}(h)$ is a symplectic transformation,
   i.e., $(\mathrm{D}\varphi)^TJ\,\mathrm{D}\varphi=J=\begin{pmatrix}0&I\\-I&0 \end{pmatrix}$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As said, use

```latex
\caption{The flow map $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_0,h)=\mathbf{x}(h)$ is a symplectic transformation,
   i.e., $(\mathrm{D}\varphi)^TJ\,\mathrm{D}\varphi=J=\protect\begin{pmatrix}0&I\\-I&0 \protect\end{pmatrix}$.}
```

if you cannot update your TeX distribution.

[image]

Without `\usepackage{caption}` and the `\captionsetup` line you get

[image]